# Wrap an ssh2 connection neatly and pass commands

Tags: beginner, rust, tcp, wrapper, ssh

I want to structure this better but don't think I'm handling results well. I'm used to python and I think my flow is way off. Is this bad design?

Should my results be Result<String, Error>?

I'm concerned mainly about structure and less on the usefulness, but happy for any kind of input.

```
struct SSHE3 {
    host: String,
    user: String,
    pass: String,
    session: Option<Session>, //Option to populate during connect()
}
impl SSHE3 {
    fn new(host: String, user: String, pass: String) -> SSHE3 {
        SSHE3 { host, user, pass, session:None }
    }
    fn connect(&mut self) -> Result<String, String>{
        if let Ok(tcp) = TcpStream::connect(&self.host){
            self.session = Some(Session::new().unwrap());

            self.session.as_mut().unwrap().set_tcp_stream(tcp);
            self.session.as_mut().unwrap().handshake().unwrap();
            
            match self.session.as_mut().unwrap().userauth_password(&self.user, &self.pass) {
                Ok(_) => return Ok("Connected".to_string()),
                Err(_) => return Err("Failed to authenticate".to_string())
            };
        }
        else {
            Err("Failed to connect".to_string())
        }
    }
    fn exec(&mut self, command: &str) -> Result<String, String> {
        match self.session.as_mut().unwrap().channel_session() {
            Ok(mut channel) => {
                channel.exec(command).unwrap();
                
                let mut s = String::new();
                channel.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
                match channel.wait_close() {
                    Ok(_) => return Ok(s),
                    Err(e) => return Err(e.to_string())
                };
            },
            Err(_) => return Err("Failed to get session".to_string())
        };
    }
}

fn main() {

    let host = "10.254.9.93:22".to_string();
    let user = "me".to_string();
    let pass = "nothing".to_string();

    let mut connection = SSHE3::new(host, user, pass);
    match connection.connect() {
        Ok(_) => {
            println!("{}",connection.exec("ls -a /").unwrap());
        }
        Err(e) => println!("{}", e)
    };
}
```